# Encoding Title, Subtitle and Text using BERT

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model

I have a use case where I want to generate embeddings using BERT. I have 3 columns viz. Title, Subtitle and Text. I want to generate BERT embeddings using all 3 columns. Now, the simplest way is to concatenate all the 3 columns but I want to introduce the importance of title, subtitle and text. Title and subtitle are more important than the text itself. How do I achieve this?

I am using [sentence-transformer](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers) in python to generate BERT embeddings.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I don't know your purpose of the network. 

Maybe,you want to classfy the text or something.

Comment: Yes, I am performing Multi-label classification in a dataless setting.